# Tab navigation problems

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-tabhost, android-view

I am using tabs in the activity class using TabHost.

```
TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
tabHost.setup();
Test testObj = new Test(this);
spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
spec2.setIndicator("Tab 2");
spec2.setContent(testObj);
```

And each view is assigned to a view that implements TabFactory.

```
public class Test implements TabContentFactory {
@Override
public View createTabContent(String arg0) {

    v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab1, null);

    /**
     * Add your code here for buttons/list etc
     * An object lookup for your Button: 
     */
    b = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    return v;
}
public void setListViewNames() {
   //create a custom list view
}
public void setDetailedView() {
   //opens another detailed view when user clicks on any item on the list
   //here i use ViewGroup to remove the first view created in setListViewNames()
}
}
```

On button click, a listView is created. Clicking on any item will take to another listView. The first listView is removed as:

```
ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
viewGroup.removeView(v);
View v1 = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_fullpicture, null);
viewGroup.addView(v1);
```

But when I go to tab one and then click on tab two, the following error is thrown.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1668): at android.widget.TabHost$FactoryContentStrategy.tabClosed        
(TabHost.java:658)
```

How do I effectively navigate in the tabs? I could not find a way to reload the tab view every time it is clicked.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is unclear, what you are trying to achieve. Can you tell why arent you setting views in different tabs. Can you tell where this code is called from "ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();"

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question. Calls to ViewGroup is made from setDetailedView() in Test class which removes the initial list view created in setListViewNames()

Comment: the application has three tabs. Each tab is assigned to a view. In each tab, several views are built on top of it. That's how it works!